# strange turtle.undo() behavior python

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm new to python. I am writing a GUI [Turtle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html) program. when i try to do the following sometimes it rolls back only once and sometimes it keeps on rolling back until the very start. can someone tell me what's i'm doing wrong.

```
for index in range(0, 50):
  turtle.undo()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: First: ["Number of available undo actions is determined by the size of the undobuffer."](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.undo)  Have you tried calling [`setundobuffer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.setundobuffer) to make sure it's at least 50?

Comment: i read that but i didn't know how to make sure of buffer size - i check it now - thanks

Comment: Beyond that: You need to create a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Show us minimal code (and steps to reproduce) that make it roll back only once, and code (and steps) that make it roll back all the way. Without that, all we can say is, "Well, if you write one program it'll do one thing, if you write another it'll do another, without seeing your program it's hard to tell why it didn't do what you expected."

Comment: @abarnert one thing. turtle.setundobuffer(50) means telling the turtle to rollback 50 step ??? no for loop needed?

Comment: No, it tells the turtle to remember its last 50 steps, so you can call `undo` 50 times in a row and it'll remember how to undo all of them.